# Webdriver.io - Unable to perform drag drop on angular gridster component

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, gridster

I did try following options:

- Headless mode
- minimized browser
- native dragAndDrop method

`await srcEle.dragAndDrop(desEle);`

- performActions

```
await browser.performActions([
            {
                type: 'pointer',
                id: 'finger1',
                parameters: { pointerType: 'mouse' },
                actions: [
                    { type: 'pointerMove', duration: 0, x: parseInt(sourceX + 20), y: parseInt(sourceY + 20) },
                    { type: 'pointerDown', button: 0 },
                    { type: 'pause', duration: 10 },
                    { type: 'pointerMove', duration: 0, origin: 'pointer', x: parseInt(sourceX + 120), y: parseInt(sourceY + 20) },
                   
                    { type: 'pointerUp', button: 0 },
                ],
            },
        ]);
```

- browser.buttonDown -> browser.moveToElement -> browser.buttonUp

```
    await browser.moveToElement(srcEle.elementId)
    await browser.pause(1000);
    await browser.buttonDown(0)
    await browser.pause(1000);
    await browser.moveToElement(desEle.elementId)
    await browser.pause(1000);
    await browser.buttonUp(0)
```

It seems like the cursor is moving but the element is not dropped.

Using "chromedriver": "^92.0.0", "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.1.0", "@wdio/cli": "^7.7.3",

For example visit - https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/emptyCell

Comment: Please add a reproducible example

Comment: @PDHide - Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Able to perform using JS...

````
 const JS_HTML5_DND = 'function e(e,t,n,i){var r=a.createEvent("DragEvent");r.initMouseEvent(t,!0,!0,o,0,0,0,c,g,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),Object.defineProperty(r,"dataTransfer",{get:function(){return d}}),e.dispatchEvent(r),o.setTimeout(i,n)}var t=arguments[0],n=arguments[1],i=arguments[2]||0,r=arguments[3]||0;if(!t.draggable)throw new Error("Source element is not draggable.");var a=t.ownerDocument,o=a.defaultView,l=t.getBoundingClientRect(),u=n?n.getBoundingClientRect():l,c=l.left+(l.width>>1),g=l.top+(l.height>>1),s=u.left+(u.width>>1)+i,f=u.top+(u.height>>1)+r,d=Object.create(Object.prototype,{_items:{value:{}},effectAllowed:{value:"all",writable:!0},dropEffect:{value:"move",writable:!0},files:{get:function(){return this._items.Files}},types:{get:function(){return Object.keys(this._items)}},setData:{value:function(e,t){this._items[e]=t}},getData:{value:function(e){return this._items[e]}},clearData:{value:function(e){delete this._items[e]}},setDragImage:{value:function(e){}}});if(n=a.elementFromPoint(s,f),!n)throw new Error("The target element is not interactable and need to be scrolled into the view.");u=n.getBoundingClientRect(),e(t,"dragstart",101,function(){var i=n.getBoundingClientRect();c=i.left+s-u.left,g=i.top+f-u.top,e(n,"dragenter",1,function(){e(n,"dragover",101,function(){n=a.elementFromPoint(c,g),e(n,"drop",1,function(){e(t,"dragend",1,callback)})})})})';

    await browser.execute(JS_HTML5_DND, srcEle, desEle); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use draganddrop method

```
describe("amp validation", () => {
   it("amp valtation testing", async () => {
      await browser.url('https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/drag')  

      await browser.maximizeWindow()
      let elemlist = await $$('gridster-item[class="ng-star-inserted"]')
      await browser.pause(5000)
      await elemlist[0].dragAndDrop(elemlist[3])
      await browser.pause(5000)
   })
})
```